# How to Fix OpenSSL Error with Sagepay Opayo

Tags: openssl, opayo

Opayo changed their Live SSL environment which is causing an error -

```
SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed; Try to connect to: https://live.sagepay.com:443/gateway/service/vspdirect-register.vsp
```

The problem is briefly mentioned on their [support monitor page](https://www.opayo.co.uk/support/support/system-monitor) -

```
24 March 2021 - 15:57
Our development teams have updated our security certificates in our Live environment.

Some vendors may experience SSL certificate issues related to this, this will require you to ‘pull’ the latest root certificate in order to resolve this.

You can access our site (https://live.sagepay.com/mysagepay/login.msp) in a browser and pull the latest root certificate down for this.

Apologies for any disruption this may have caused.
```

There is no information on which certificate to pull, or what to do with it after it is pulled!  Their login page has 3 certificates all with cert & chains.

Which SSL do I download and what to do with it after it is pulled?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've already managed to get to the bottom or this, however if not then you need to find a way to update your server's trusted root certificates.

The best way to resolve this is to speak with your hosting provider as they would be best to advise on your specific environment.

If your server's root certificates are up to date and the issue is still ongoing this means the software trying to make the connection such as cURL or PHP cannot access the folder or file with the relevant trusted certificates. Again your hosting provider or web developer should be able to diagnose this.

The certificate you need in the trust store is  "Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2"
Fingerprint SHA256: 43df5774b03e7fef5fe40d931a7bedf1bb2e6b42738c4e6d3841103d3aa7f339
Pin SHA256: du6FkDdMcVQ3u8prumAo6t3i3G27uMP2EOhR8R0at/U=
[Certificate analysis of sagepay](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=live.sagepay.com)

It's always advisable to have a working trust store with up to date root certificates to ensure your apps can communicate securely with websites and APIs.

Comment: yeah I stopped using sagepay.  They changed the root cert without notice.  Apparently they have been doing it for years but it hasnt caused an issue as their monitor page said. So yes it would be nice to work with up to date certs.  Every other program can access the root certs so not sure it would be a PHP or cURL issue.